# random of function in sql for two different fields which are in two different tables

Tags: mysql

I want to perform a random function `rand(100001, 1000000)` which have to generate random no `s` which has to be unique in two different field.

To explain it clearly
I have two tables say table `A` which has a record with status `Submitted`, `Approved` and table `B` which have only records with status `Rejected`.

I am having a field called `ackno` in table `A` as well as table `B` which needs to be random no and unique in comparison with both table field.

Is this possible ? Can anybody give a solution ?

Comment: ackno sounds like account number. Can't you use an autoinc key for that? How are you making sure you don't get the same number as you already have?

Answer (score 0):

A random number won't be unique. In this case you have 999.999 numbers, based on the number of records you can calculate the probability that 2 numbers are the same.

I see 2 ways to ensure a unique value.

First of all you could use `autoincrement`. Let `table A` start with 1 and `table B` start with 1.000.000. As long as `table A` has less than a million rows, you're good.

Second is to use the [`uuid`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). A UUID is a 128-bit number represented by a utf8 string of five hexadecimal numbers in aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee format.

Note that both methods are deliver guessable values. If that's a problem, you could add a random number to it and encode it, like:

```
SELECT SHA2(CONCAT(UUID(), RAND()), 256);
```

Comment: @Raji Please give my answer a try.

Comment: I found two ways to handled this 1) having sequence in sql and calling it wen ever i wanted to insert record into these tables so that each table's column will be unique all the time. 2) 2 nd option s handling it code level (in my case in yii)  will generate a random of no before inserting it into table and check with both the table whether this no exist in those and if so will regenerate the random no again ...